# Cannot extract data from downloaded page with 'match[]'

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following Ruby code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rest_client'

url = 'http://asdf.com'
response = RestClient.get(url)
b = response.body

result = b.match(/<head>(.*)<\/head>/)[1]
puts result
```

when I try to parse this page to get the header I get the following error:

```
7:in `<main>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

What am I doing wrong?(apart from using regex to parse html. I'm just experimenting)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At a guess the `<head>` tag isn't all on one line. Try:

```
result = b.match(/<head>(.*)<\/head>/m)[1]
```

(Note the `m`, switching you to multiline mode).

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong?(apart from using regex to parse html. I'm just experimenting)

You are using regex to parse HTML, that's what you are doing wrong. In this particular case, your regex doesn't match anything, therefore `Regexp#match` returns `nil` and you are trying to call `[]` on `nil`.

The document you are parsing looks like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <title>asdf</title>
  </head>
…
```

I.e. there are line breaks in the document. An HTML parser ignores linebreaks, because it knows that they are insignificant in HTML, but your regex doesn't.

Comment: This mistake would be the same and it has nothing to do with the data being html. Any string could contain line breaks. I thought .* would match those too.

Comment: +1 for the reminder about not trying to parse html using regexps: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html ;)